# Issues returning variable values from one module to another when GUI onclick command is made

Tags: python, variables, user-interface, dictionary

I am writing a small dictionary program where the user can open another window to add a new word and definition so that it can be added to the main dictionary and later searched for.

My problem is that although the user can open a new window to add a word and its definition, when the submit button is clicked, the main dictionary isn't updated. Instead it throws up an error, `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'word' referenced before assignment`.

I seem to have a problem passing the new word / definition variable values back into the main program.

Main Program Code (filename: Libraryv2.py)

```
from tkinter import *
import libraryentry



def click():
    entered_text = entry.get() #collect text from text entry box
    output.delete(0.0,END) #clears text box - start clearing from 0.0 (from line 0) to END (after last character)
    try:
        definition = my_glossary[entered_text] #this takes the entered text and uses it as a key for the dictionary, the value found is assigned to definition
    except:
        definition = "No word found in dictionary, try again!"
    output.insert(END, definition) #this inserts the contents of variable 'definition' at the beginning (END) - because it was cleared before, END is the at the start

def clickentry():
    word = libraryentry.main(word)
    definition= libraryentry.main(definition)
    my_glossary[word] = definition

window = Tk()

window.title("My Little Dictionary")

#Create the Label
Label(window, text="Enter the word you want defining:").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

#create entry box
entry=Entry(window, width=20, bg="light green")
entry.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

#create submit button
Button(window, text="Submit", width=5, command=click).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

#create second label
Label(window, text="\nDefinition").grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)

#create text box
output=Text(window, width=75, height=6, wrap=WORD, background="light green")
output.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)

#create submit button to open enter new definition window
Button(window, text="Enter a New Definition", width=20, command=clickentry).grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W)


#Create the Dictionary
my_glossary =   {
                "Algorithm": "Step by step instructions to perform a task",
                "Python": "High-Level Programming language used to write light weight programs",
                "Flow-Chart": "A way to present an algorthim graphically"
                }

window.mainloop()
```

Edit Window Module (filename libraryentry.py):

```
from tkinter import *

def click2():
    word = entry1.get() #collect text from text entry box
    definition = entry2.get() #collect text from text entry box
    return (word,definition)

def main():
    window = Tk()

    window.title("Library entry")

    #Create the Label
    Label(window, text="Enter the word you want to add:").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

    #create entry box
    entry1=Entry(window, width=20, bg="light green")
    entry1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

    #create second label
    Label(window, text="\nDefinition").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

    #create entry box
    entry2=Entry(window, width=50, bg="light green")
    entry2.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)

    #create submit button
    Button(window, text="Submit", width=5, command=click2).grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)

    return (word, definition)

    window.mainloop()
```

Any help in solving this issues would be gratefully received. Why are is my new word / definition not being passed back into the main program properly?

Many thanks

Comment: You do `word = libraryentry.main(word)`, but `libraryentry.main` doesn't take any parameters. Also, in your second code block, `window.mainloop()` will never execute, because the function stops as soon as it reaches a `return` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
word = libraryentry.main(word)
```

It doesn't make sense to do `libraryentry.main(word)`, because `word` doesn't exist yet, and `main` doesn't take any parameters anyway.

```
word = libraryentry.main()
```

Now you'll get `NameError: name 'word' is not defined` in `libraryentry` because you're returning `(word, definition)` before the second window even appears, so there's a 0% chance the user could possibly enter the word and click "Submit". Move the `return` to the end of the function.

```
window.mainloop()
return (word, definition)
```

Now you'll get `NameError: name 'entry1' is not defined` in `click2` because variables defined in one function aren't visible in another one. Refactor `libraryentry` to use a class, so attributes of `self` are sharable between methods.

```
from tkinter import *

class DefinitionWindow(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, root, click_callback):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, root)
        self.click_callback = click_callback
        self.title("Library entry")

        #Create the Label
        Label(self, text="Enter the word you want to add:").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

        #create entry box
        self.word_entry=Entry(self, width=20, bg="light green")
        self.word_entry.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

        #create second label
        Label(self, text="\nDefinition").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

        #create entry box
        self.definition_entry = Entry(self, width=50, bg="light green")
        self.definition_entry.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)

        #create submit button
        Button(self, text="Submit", width=5, command=self.clicked).grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)

    def clicked(self):
        self.click_callback(self.word_entry.get(), self.definition_entry.get())
        self.destroy()
```

In addition to the OO structure, notice that there's no `main` that returns a word and definition. This is due to the asynchronous nature of Tkinter - if `main` waits for the definition window to close, then `window.mainloop` can't continue executing, and everything will hang. So it's necessary to instead register a callback, which will get executed some time in the future once the user makes their choice.

```
def clickentry():
    def definition_submitted(word, definition):
        my_glossary[word] = definition

    definition_window = libraryentry.DefinitionWindow(window, definition_submitted)
```

Result:

[image: Before entering a new definition]

[image: Entering a new definition]

[image: After entering a new definition]

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and sorry for not getting back sooner. Excellent answer!!!

Comment: Just got into work and tried out your suggestions but now I am getting the following error each time I press the 'ENTER A NEW DEFINITION' button:

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1399, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "H:\Departments\COMPUTER STUDIES\3 A-Level Computing Curriculum\F452\Programming Examples\GUI\Dictionary Program\Libraryv3.py", line 20, in clickentry
    definition_window = libraryentryv2.DefinitionWindow(window, definition_submitted)

Comment: File "H:\Departments\COMPUTER STUDIES\3 A-Level Computing Curriculum\F452\Programming Examples\GUI\Dictionary Program\libraryentryv2.py", line 6, in __init__
    Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1674, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
TypeError: must be str or None, not Tk

Comment: That error is complaining that a function was passed in as the second argument to `Tk` when calling `Toplevel.__init__`. I pasted in the wrong version of `DefinitionWindow` while I was writing this answer. Sorry about that. I've edited in the version that supports callbacks.

Comment: Ok, so clearly I am new to this. I'm really struggling to understand the mechanics of the call_back. In Def clicked, are both the entered word and definition added to the click_callback variable? Is it a variable or a tuple? If click_callback does hold these values then how do these values pass into the Def definition_submitted function? I understand that this function can be called when the DefinitionWindow object is created but how does it go from click_callback into the word/definition parameters of definition_submitted? Sorry if this is wasting your time but I really want to get this.

Comment: _"Is it a variable or a tuple?"_ `click_callback` is a variable that contains a function, and behaves like an ordinary function would. `click_callback(a,b)` executes the function it contains, using `a` and `b` as arguments to that function. Effectively, in this context, `self.click_callback(self.word_entry.get(), self.definition_entry.get())` is the same as `definition_submitted(self.word_entry.get(), self.definition_entry.get())`. (Although the latter won't work because `definition_submitted` isn't accessible from the libraryentry module. That's why we're using callbacks in the first place.)